# Insertar información de formulario múltiples veces // ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Cordial saludo

- Tengo un formulario para insertar la información de X producto.
- Me gustaría, desde este formulario ingresar varias veces X números de productos sin necesidad de estar recargando la página.
- Al oprimir el botón registrar, ingresa el producto. Al oprimir el botón “limpiar” quedan vacíos los campos, pero si ingreso los datos de un nuevo producto, al oprimir al botón registrar no funciona, se recarga la página.
- Uso AJAX, pero debo recargar la página para que funcione.
  Quedo atento,
  Gracias por su ayuda
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante Ajax, llamo el controlador- addproduct-action.php

```
$("#add_register_product").submit(function(event) {
  var form1 = $("#add_register_product");
  form1.validate();
  if (form1.valid()==true){
    $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);
    var parametros = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "core/app/action/complement/ajax/addproduct-action.php",
      data: parametros,
      beforeSend: function(objeto){
        $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
      },
      success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
        $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).remove();
          });
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

El archivo `addproduct-action.php`, tiene este código

```
$user = new ProductData();
$user->brand_id = $_POST["brand_id"];
$user->provider_id = $_POST["provider_id"];
$user->name = $_POST["newname"];
$user->price_purchase = $_POST["price_purchase"];
$user->code = $_POST["newcode"];
$user->barcode = $_POST["barcode"];
$user->description = $_POST["description"];
$user->inventary_min = $_POST["inventary_min"];
$user->category = $_POST["category"];
$user->is_active =1;
$user->add();
```

Como indico, al realizar el primero registro OK, pero al intentar realizar otro registro no funciona. Agradezco su gran ayuda

Comment: s sucede eso es por que estas callendo en un error en el codigo, revisa la consola para verificar que esta pasando, pero si usas laravel y otro MVC puede que te este restringiendo las peticiones post